# Click command doesn't work on a element

Tags: selenium-ide

We're using this components in our [web application](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxToolbar/samples/01_init/08_events.html).

On the page you can see a toolbar containing some buttons. If you click on any of the buttons it writes a log into the logbar.

The problem is I cannot record this behavior using the Selenium IDE. The IDE creates a command, but when I execute the command nothing happens. Not even an error is logged.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Execute your script at slow speed

Use xpath to identify element like

```
clickAt  | //div[text()='New']
```

To click New button

Comment: Yes this works for the New button, but doesn't work on the cut,copy and paste buttons

Comment: True, with help of this you can click on New and Print only

Comment: Do you know any way around this ? How to click on the other ones ?

Comment: looking for same 1..will find solution for this one ASAP..in mean time if you got, then do share over here

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't fire on the other buttons.It's also a div.

Answer (score 1):

I visited the site http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxToolbar/samples/01_init/08_events.html

I got the xpath by using xpath checker as below:

Cut - `id('toolbarObj')/x:div[5]/x:div[11]/x:div`

Copy - `id('toolbarObj')/x:div[5]/x:div[12]/x:div`

Paste - `id('toolbarObj')/x:div[5]/x:div[13]/x:div`

You can use the modified xpath as:

```
selenium.click("//div[@id='toolbarObj']/div[5]/div[11]/div");//Cut
selenium.click("//div[@id='toolbarObj']/div[5]/div[12]/div");//Copy
selenium.click("//div[@id='toolbarObj']/div[5]/div[13]/div");//Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this will help but it surely helped me

if there is any text you have to type and then click on any element or button

There are two ways
First use "`sendKeys`" to type then "click" the required element will work.
For Eg In `flipkart.com` "type" doesn't work but "`sendKeys`" does

Second is 
Use "type" then press enter instead of click using "sendKeys" in target have the field that you were typing and in value must have "`${KEY_ENTER}`"

Eg will help you better
**First Method:**
[image: The First Method]

**Second Method:**
[image: The Second Method]

Both Worked for me fortunately

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the selenium script starts too fast. I guess the component you're using generates a bunch of HTML for all the buttons. If the script starts too early the html might  not have been generated yet. Try running the selenium script slower.

Also: I think selenium uses XPath to get to the HTML elements in the page. Are you sure that the selenium script is referring to the correct HTML node? You can check this by looking at the selenium script (it's XML) and look what XPath selector it uses for the button.

What also could be the case is that selenium might not be able to fire click events on non clickable targets (the buttons are divs), but I don't think that is the case. You could try though.

Comment: Its not because of the execution speed. I run the command when the page is fully loaded.The XPath is also correct, I did check it. INteresting is when I execute clickAt command on the New button it does work,but on the  cut, paste and copy buttons.

Answer (score 0):

What about if you click on the img itself instead of the div? E.g:

```
//img[contains(@src, 'paste')]
```

When you click on 'Find' on the Selenium IDE, does it actually highlight something on the page?

Comment: Yes, it does. It highlights the correct div. But the click event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE isn't perfect at recording when javascript has loaded items to the page, so it may need manual assistance.

Have you tried waiting for the element to load before trying to click on it?  I might suggest inserting a waitForElementPresent command, like waitForElementPresent | #toolbarObj before trying the click.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of doing that:

```
package riponalwasim.selenium.webdriver.stackoverflow;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CutCopyPaste {
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseUrl;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        baseUrl = "http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxToolbar/samples/01_init/08_events.html";
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCutCopyPaste() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='New']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='toolbarObj']/div[5]/div[11]/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='toolbarObj']/div[5]/div[12]/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='toolbarObj']/div[5]/div[13]/div")).click();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

it will take more than 1ms for javascript work . So just add like 'pause 1000'